# Changing default href to data-href using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, href, attr

".setAttribute()" etc. I used some values but without success.

href > data-href

by default there is an href element

`"<a class="wp-block-post-excerpt__more-link" href="#link" tabindex="0">View Details</a>"`

I want to change this element to data-href using js. Also, I don't want to add another one.

`"<a class="wp-block-post-excerpt__more-link" data-href="#link" tabindex="0">View Details</a>"`

I am using the following js code, both href and data-href are added and I want to remove it as a link.

```
$('a[href]').each(function() { 
 $(this).attr('data-href', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `href` attribute? As in `element.removeAttribute('href')`

Comment: If you want to remove an attribute, use [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) (jQuery) or [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) (DOM).

Comment: using this works, I hadn't thought of it :( thank you, but I'm using a fancybox iframe and it throws an error" Fancybox.bind('.variable-group li a[data-href""]'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using vanilla Javascript:

- Grab the `href` attribute, set it in a variable `oldHref`
- Remove `href` using [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)
- Add new data-attribute of that `oldHref` variable using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
let link = document.querySelector('.wp-block-post-excerpt__more-link');
let oldHref = link.href;
link.removeAttribute('href');
link.setAttribute("data-href", oldHref);
```

```html
<a class="wp-block-post-excerpt__more-link" href="#link" tabindex="0">View Details</a>
```

Comment: thanks you for your help. but it only works for the first link.

Comment: Glad it helped! you could do that for all the elements by using  querySelectorAll instead of querySelector which get the first element!

Comment: Yes, Taher. that's how it works.
where do you think i go wrong here
Fancybox.bind('a', {
href : $('a[data-href]'),
type: "iframe",
       });